# Dojo datagrid with additional data

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I want to create a dojo datagrid which has, in addition to all the fields in the datastore, a column that I want to populate manually. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an empty property in your data items, declare a column that maps to that empty property, and make the column editable.